# Building a django queryset with primary keys in JSON array field

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

Suppose we have a model like,

```
class Table1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Table2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    table1_pks = ArrayField(models.IntegerField())
```

with the entries,

Table1

```
id | name
----------
1  | hydrogen
2  | helium
3  | lithium
4  | berylium
```

Table2

```
id | name | table1_pks           Mapping to table1
-----------------------
 3 | fe   | {2, 3}               -> Multiple
 6 | br   | {1, 3, 4}            -> Multiple
 7 | cr   | {2}                  -> Single
10 | be   | {2, 4}               -> Multiple
12 | sn   | {1, 2, 3, 4}         -> All
15 | ra   | {1}                  -> Single
17 | pu   | {1, 2, 3, 4}         -> All
19 | ti   | {2, 5}               -> Single
```

How to create a `queryset` on `Table2` so that the results are ordered/grouped in the sequence of All, Multiple and Single.

Note that the last entry `19` in `Table2` is called `Single` because the entry for `5` doesn't exists in `Table1`. So any consideration to compare the length of each entry in `table1_pks` against the `total rows` in `Table1` might not work.

Comment: Is there a reason why you did not use a `ManyToManyField`?

Comment: This is an existing system and I'm trying to modify couple of things around it. Why not `ManyToManyField`- I'm not really sure yet on this design decisions taken on this here.